# Airflow - Why is there no trigger rule "One done"? Am i missing something?

Tags: python-2.7, python-2.x, airflow

I am trying to do this flow in an airflow dag.

- Task 1: check if file exists in s3 (s3 sensor). If no new file is found, skip to task 4.
- Task 2: if task 1 meets the criteria, delete the existing file in the local folder
- Task 3: if task 2 is finished, download the s3 file into the local folder
- Task 4: in either case, update table (using the only file in the folder)

I am not sure what trigger rule to add in the task 4. If i add one_failed, obviously the task wont be executed if the file exists.

If i add "all_done" it wont be executed because in either path, the dag will be skipping tasks (that's the whole purpose).

How should I go about it? I think i am missing something here...

Thanks everyone.

*UPDATE*

It also seems that my s3keysensor is not triggering "Fail" status when timed out. It appears in yellow even though the log shows "Snap, time is out".

Should be triggering Fail. This is from the documentation.
"    Sensor operators keep executing at a time interval and succeed when
        a criteria is met and fail if and when they time out."

This message appears in the console "These tasks are deadlocked: {...}." and the dag does not keep running. Can't get task 4 running! I am also trying it with a backfill for the same start and end date, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. It seems that Airflow cant have "empty paths". So you just have to add a dummy branch-false and then "ONE_SUCEED" on task 4.

Simple as that.